# How to take jquery autocomplete values instead of labels? As well as guide me if I add dependence autocomplete?

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

How to take values instead of taking labels

I'm getting names but I want there values like "ActionScript" value is 1 "AppleScript" value is 2

As well as guide me if I add dependence autoselect, below is my code

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
    print_r($_POST);
}
?>    
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
      $( function() {
        var availableTags = [
          "ActionScript",
          "AppleScript",
          "Asp",
          "BASIC",
          "C",
          "C++",
          "Clojure",
          "COBOL",
          "ColdFusion",
          "Erlang",
          "Fortran",
          "Groovy",
          "Haskell",
          "Java",
          "JavaScript",
          "Lisp",
          "Perl",
          "PHP",
          "Python",
          "Ruby",
          "Scala",
          "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags
        });
      } );
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="" method="POST"> 
    <div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
      <input id="tags" name="tags">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

[PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tevx-szk6)

Answer (score 3):

You can define a select callback, get the chosen value, get the source list and fetch the index of the selected item in the list:

```js
 $( function() {
        var availableTags = [
          "ActionScript",
          "AppleScript",
          "Asp",
          "BASIC",
          "C",
          "C++",
          "Clojure",
          "COBOL",
          "ColdFusion",
          "Erlang",
          "Fortran",
          "Groovy",
          "Haskell",
          "Java",
          "JavaScript",
          "Lisp",
          "Perl",
          "PHP",
          "Python",
          "Ruby",
          "Scala",
          "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags,
          select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var source = $( "#tags" ).autocomplete("option", "source" );
            var value = ui.item.value;
            $(this).val(source.indexOf(value)+1);
            // console.log(source.indexOf(value)+1, $(this));
          }
        });
      } );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="" method="POST"> 
    <div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
      <input id="tags" name="tags">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want there values not index @kad

Comment: Or how can I replace index values with original values

Comment: You can set the index values in the input agian using jquery `val`. As far as I understand what you really need

Comment: I have updated the code, you need to prevent the default behavior of the event and set the value using `.val`

Comment: I tried a number of ways.  I'm getting only index value @kad

Comment: I do not get what value you really want, you have both the actual value `C++` and you said in the question you want 1,2.... I assumed this is the index, are you referring to other value? Such as a database id for the autocomplete list?

Comment: Yes, It should come database. i will take those id's as my values

Comment: You need to pass the source as key-value pair and have a hidden input that holds the id and the text input will hold the label. Here is an example that you can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/LCv8L/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138309/discussion-between-siddhu-siddhartha-roy-and-kad).

Comment: sorry, am blocked by proxy, just follow the example and this answer, it is the same concept